# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method group join

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

How to fix this error? And why it raising?

> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[FRecipes.Models.Component]
>   ToList[Component](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1

```
public ActionResult ShowDishes(int id)
    {
        DishesWithCategory dish = new DishesWithCategory();
        dish.category = id;
        List<Item> Test = new List<Item>();
        var result1 = (
        from d in FRE.Dish
        join c in FRE.Component on d.DishID equals c.DishID into items
        select new Item { DishID = d.DishID, components = items.ToList() }
        ).ToList();

        return View();
    }
```

Models:

```
public class DishesWithCategory
{
    public List<Item> item { get; set; }
    public int category { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int DishID { get; set; }

    public string DishName { get; set; }

    public List<Component> components { get; set; }
}

public partial class Component
{
    public int ComponentID { get; set; }
    public int DishID { get; set; }
    public string AmountID { get; set; }
    public string NameID { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to replace this line:

```
select new Item { DishID = d.DishID, components = items.ToList() }
```

with this one:

```
select new Item { DishID = d.DishID, components = items }
```

The error is quite clear: `ToList()` function cannot be translated in that context.

Comment: Strange you fix works only with replacement public List<Component> components { get; set; }, with public IEnumerable<Component> components { get; set; }.But works. Why ToList do notwork in that context?

Comment: @A191919 LINQ to Entities in this instance is trying to translate your query to SQL in order to execute it and does not know how to translate `.ToList()` to SQL.

Comment: `ToList` inside a projection (select) does not affect SQL query generation, but the query result materialization. Most probably you are using outdated EF version, with the most recent at the moment 6.1.3 it works w/o problem.